# Looking for a better way to access Azure SQL Databases?

Tags: azure-sql-database, ssms, firewall

Right now, whenever I want to access my databases on MS Azure SQL, I need to sign in and add my IP address to the list of IPs in the firewall and only then can I run queries.

Is there a better way in which I can verify my computer to always access the DB without adding myself to the firewall white list each time.

I know getting a fixed IP myself or adding an ip range of 0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255 would essentially solve the problem, but any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just run the following PowerShell script to automatically create the firewall rule for you, then you just need to run SQL Server Management Studio or Azure Data Studio to connect to Azure SQL Database.

This script will add your current IP to the firewall white list.

```
$subscriptionName = 'Your Subscription'
$ipGetCommand = 'http://www.iplocation.net/find-ip-address' 
$firewallRule = 'My-Home'
$serverName = "Your Server Name";
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$queryResult = $webclient.DownloadString($ipGetCommand)
$queryResult -match '\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b'
$currentPublicIp = $($matches[0])

Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $subscriptionName



If ((Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServerFirewallRule -ServerName $serverName -RuleName $firewallRule) -eq $null) {
    New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerFirewallRule -ServerName $serverName -RuleName $firewallRule -StartIpAddress $currentPublicIp -EndIpAddress $currentPublicIp
}
else {
    Set-AzureSqlDatabaseServerFirewallRule -ServerName $serverName -RuleName $firewallRule -StartIpAddress $currentPublicIp -EndIpAddress $currentPublicIp
}
```

You can also create an schedule task on your computer to run this PowerShell for you when you start your computer.

Comment: Will it clear all the old ip addresses that were added to the white list?

Comment: It will create a rule name "My-Home" if it is not created. If it is created, it will change the IP address to the current client IP.